# Performance issue with php remote url fread operation

Tags: php, fopen, fread

I have a performance problem with my script (below).
The fread operation takes a lot of time, I get times like:

```
$time_split2 == 0.00135s

$time_split3 == 15.01747s
```

I have tested it even with a remote script that does nothing except echoing OK message - there is still the aprox. 15 seconds execution time

What could be the problem or how could I solve it another way.
I would prefer not to use curl (would that speed up things?) since the curl is not always installed with PHP, and I would like my code to be portable

```
    $opts = array('http' =>
      array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => array('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Custom-header: test'),
        'content' => $postdata,
        'timeout' => 60
      )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

    $time_split = microtime(true);

    $fp = fopen('http://someremotedomain/script.php', 'r', false, $context);
    $time_split2 = microtime(true);

    while(!feof($fp))
      $result .= fread($fp, 4096);
    fclose($fp);
    $time_split3 = microtime(true);

    $time_split2 = round($time_split2 - $time_split, 5);
    $time_split3 = round($time_split3 - $time_split, 5);
```

**UPDATE**

I have used your suggestions - file_get_contents() + Connection: close - it doesn't work yet  - file_get_contents() works with a delay and returns an empty string but - I have isolated the problem, here is the $postdata:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
   array('body' => $mail_html_content,
         'from' => 'test <test@test.com>',
         'to' => 'test2 <test2@test.com>',
        )
);
```

when I remove 'body' from the array - file_get_contents() works fine and without any delays - how could this create a problem - $mail_html_content contains just a simple HTML string and it is not a big string

**UPDATE 2**

I have isolated the problem even more - when the length of the $postdata string exceeds 1024 chars, file_get_contents() starts to return empty values, below that value everything works fine, since method POST isn't limited by length of the data (at least for such low numbers) what could be the problem now??

Comment: try file_get_contents('http://someremotedomain/script.php');

Comment: Try adding a header: **Connection: close**

Answer (score 0):

You should try [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents) instead of use `while(!feof($fp))`.

E.g.

```
  /* EDIT: header should be something like that */
$opts = array( 
    'http' => array(
        'method'=>"POST", 
        'header'=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8",
    ),
); 
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$result = file_get_contents('http://someremotedomain/script.php', false, $context);
```

For other header information look [here][3]
[3]: https://www.php.net/manual/it/function.stream-context-create.php

##Reason##
according to [fread][2] documentation:
[2]: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

> **Note**:
>
> If you just want to get the contents of a file into a string, use file_get_contents() as
> it has much better performance than the code above.

Comment: I added "Connection: close" and changed script to use file_get_contents() but there are two problems now:    
1. with method POST - file_get_contents() - returns an empty string - string(0) ""   2. with method GET it returns response from the remote script but it does not transmit the data ($postdata) to that script the $_GET array is empty, the but headers are transmitted OK, and I would like to use the POST method anyway

Comment: If you are trying to get content from an **https** connection, you should enable apache ssl_module, check your configuration, maybe you have to enable [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) and if your url contains special chars you should use `urlencode()`

Comment: I don't use https,  allow_url_fopen ar "on" on my test server by default, url doesn't contain any special chars - I have updated my problem/question above by adding some new findings